# How are there too many arguments in this if statement

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My *IF* statement below keeps error shooting, stating that there are too many arguments.

Why is this? Can anyone see any errors in the statement below?

```
=IF(G7="EUR",H7/1.15,L7,IF(G7="USD",H7/1.35,L7,IF(G7="AUD",H7/1.35,L7,IF(G7="CAD",H7/1.35,L7,IF(G7="NOK",H7/8.8,L7)))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IF format :

```
IF(test, exec if true, exec if false)
```

All your IFs have 4 arguments.

If I understand what you're trying to do, you should try :

```
=IF(G7="EUR",H7/1.15,IF(G7="USD",H7/1.35,IF(G7="AUD",H7/1.35,IF(G7="CAD",H7/1.35,IF(G7="NOK",H7/8.8,L7)))))
```

Answer (score 2):

All your IFs have too many arguments - `",H7/1.15,L7,IF` - The structure of `if` is:

```
=If(condition, If True, If False)
```

Only 2 commas allowed

Answer (score 1):

All of them has 4 arguments. Which is too many. They should only have three.

I do not know how you planned this, but my guess is that the solution is:

`=IF(G7="EUR",H7/1.15,IF(G7="USD",H7/1.35,IF(G7="AUD",H7/1.35,IF(G7="CAD",H7/1.35,IF(G7="NOK",H7/8.8,L7)))))`

Answer (score 1):

Your `IF` statements seem to be including too many parameters, there should just be a condition, a true and a false value. See [MSDN](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/if-HP005209118.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Possibly simpler to use a VLOOKUP function in these circumstances - set up a two column table somewhere on your worksheet with currencies in column 1 and the divisor/conversion amount for each in column 2 - name the table CurrTable then you can use this formula

`=IFERROR(H7/VLOOKUP(G7,CurrTable,2,0),L7)`